Does Genesis 49:10 mean that when Shiloh comes, then the rule of the tribe of Judah will end? Genesis 49:10
Or does it mean that even after the messiah comes, the sceptre still belong to that even after the messiah comes the scepter will still belong to a member of the tribe of Judah?
Since Israel have been dominated by other nations before Christ came, could these dominations be considered that the sceptre had departed from Judah?
Genesis 49:10 ASV
The sceptre shall not depart from Judah, Nor the ruler's staff from between his feet, Until Shiloh come: And unto him shall the obedience of the peoples be.

The answer depends on several issues, including whether shiloh (שִׁילֹה) is a place, a title, or perhaps a word related to the idea of tribute.  Some commentators (both Jewish and Christian) think it is the true title of the Messiah. The meaning of the scepter is also open to interpretation. Was a literal object or a spiritual symbol? Did it relate to rulership, spiritual authority or tribal pre-eminence? Possible understandings related to the OP's question:

Some understand the sentence as referring to the arrival of the tabernacle at Shiloh (Joshua 18:1). Soon after this the tribes were dispersed to their various allotments. Judah did not rule.
"There was no king in Israel; everyone did what was right in their own eyes." (Judges 17:6)



The prophet Ahijah was based at Shiloh, and it was he who prophesied that David's kingdom would be divided into ten northern tribes and two southern tribes because of Solomon's sin. (1 Kings 11:29) This may have been the point at which the scepter passed from Judah.

One Christian understanding is that spiritual authority passed from Judah and the Jews (representing the Old Covenant)  to Christendom (representing the New Covenant) after the coming of Jesus.

In opposition to the OP's suggestion, one Talmudic tradition (Horayot 11b:3) holds that in medieval times, “The scepter shall not depart from Judah” still  referred to the Exilarch in Babylonia, and "the ruler’s staff" refers to descendants of Rabbi Hillel, who interpret the law for the Jews.


Conclusion: The OP asks "Since Israel had been dominated by other nations before Christ came, could these dominations be considered that the sceptre had departed from Judah?" Answer: This is one of many possible interpretations.
